# Application Insights installation in layered client-server project

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm working on a project structured as N-Tier / 3-Tier Architectural Style. The layers (client-server) communicate with each other by HTTP and WCF. I want to use AppInsights to track everything in the project. However, I'm confused about where in the project to create or add AppInsight packages. I have created two instances of resources under one resource group on Azure. Then, I configured inst. key and other things regarding projects in the solution. Although I overrode handle attribute with mine(as explained in AppInsights docs), I couldn't see all call methods and exception tracks from client to server along with layers. Is it not possible to track exceptions in that project type or I'm mistaken?

**UPDATE for additional info to define problem clearly**: When I use one resource and one instrumentation key, AppInsights defines well whole project and shows relation of my solution and its dependencies. But, when one request failed due to exception in the server, I can't reach whole exception trace, just last method where request is asked from server. Because of that I use two resource instance, one for server and one for client(not real client, its like middle layer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using multiple apps/keys and multiple layers, you might need to introduce custom code to set/pass through something like a correlationId through http headers, and code that reads and uses that as application insights's "operation id".  If you do the work across different applications/ikeys, searching across the apps will become more complicated.

instead, you might want to use just one ikey across all the layers, and instead use different ikeys for different environments, like dev/staging/prod instead.

there are some examples of reading/using operationId, like this blog post:
http://blog.marcinbudny.com/2016/04/application-insights-for-owin-based.html#.WBkL24WcFaQ

where someone does something similar with OWIN.

For Exception tracking, if the exceptions are happening at one of the other asp.net layers, you might need to enable some extra settings to collect exceptions or more information for them:

http://apmtips.com/blog/2016/06/21/application-insights-for-mvc-and-mvc-web-api/